# Monitor users online using bash, and filter out bots and assets

Tags: bash, awk

I have a website that generates raw access logs. My web host doesn't have good support for viewing users online, so I've turned to SSH. Right now I am using the following bash script to see who is online:

```
watch tail -50 access.log
```

However there is a lot of junk in there. There is a bot that visits my website every 5 minutes, and whenever somebody loads a page, a bunch of assets (images, JS, CSS) also show up in the log.

Is there a way to tail the end of the file, and also filter out lines containing certain words, such as `Alexabot`, `.css`, `.png`, `.jpg`, and `.js`?

Also, it'd be ideal if the command/script would work backwards from the end of the file until 50 lines not matching the filter criteria are found, rather than just taking the last 50 lines and suppressing the spammy ones within that group.

I looked into awk for filtering, but I am stuck because I don't know how to combine awk with tail.

Comment: To get exactly 50 lines "good" output an iteration could be applied to the already given answers: set a variable `n` to `50`, start: `nOld=$n`, filter `tail -$n` and count the eliminated lines, add this number to `n` and goto start until <s>`nOld==n`</s> number of "good" lines is `50`.

Comment: The convergence of the proposed iteration might be improved when you consider the percentage of found lines to eliminate. If there is an expected percentage the start `n` can be increased appropriately, of course.

Comment: Great answers. I tweaked them a little bit and came up with this. `watch 'tail -500 access.log | awk '"'"'!/Alexabot|Googlebot|Baiduspider|bingbot|BingPreview|slurp|Daum|.css|.png|.jpg|.js/'"'"' | cut -c 1-180'` This is displaying my logs nicely.

Comment: @PS I will. I'm going to wait one more day to see if somebody posts the "exactly 50 good lines output" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `awk` version to negate multiple strings.

```
watch tail -50 access.log |awk '!/Alexabot|.css|.png|.jpg|.js/'
```

OR, if you want continuous monitoring.

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f access.log | stdbuf -iL awk '!/Alexabot|.css|.png|.jpg|.js/'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `grep` withe the `-v`, invert-match,

```
watch tail -50 access.log | grep -v -E '(Alexabot|.css|.png|.jpg|.js)'
```

The `-E` flag is for enabling `Extended Regular Expression (ERE)` syntax to allow match for multiple strings separated by `|`

You could also try disabling output buffering with `stdbuf -oL` before feeding the stream to `grep` as

```
watch tail -50 access.log | stdbuf -oL grep -v -E '(Alexabot|.css|.png|.jpg|.js)'
```

Comment: Better grep first, then tail.

Comment: @n.m.: Appreciate you comment, thought of the same way, then realized OP had used the way above to solve this problem (see comments in question). It was quite unclear how he wanted to filter it, so left it upto their convenience. Thanks!